# Adding external lib to deployments/lib/main (Quarkus)

Tags: quarkus

I need to add an external lib inside the deployments/lib/main on Dockefile, but the lib is not found by classloader. How can I add a lib that is not managed by maven inside the Quarkus app?

I'm adding the lib inside the /deployments/lib/main on the Dockerfile.

`COPY --chown=185 components/mycomponent/*.jar /deployments/lib/main`

I expected the classloader load this lib.

Comment: I have a similar need. Did you manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing will not work, because Quarkus indexes the contents of those dependencies at build time.

In your case, although the jar exists on the filesystem, Quarkus has not indexed it at build time and therefore its contents are unknown to the Quarkus classloader.

A potential solution would be to use the `legacy-jar` package format which does not do any indexing.